# Running cells with "python 3.9.6 64-bit' requires ipykernnel installed or requires an update

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipython, offline

I just recently installed vs code (version 1.59.0) on my work computer (Windows). I installed python 3.9.6 extension. Because of high security, I'm unable to install extensions via pip install, I have to go to VS code marketplace and download VSIX files and then install packages via VSIX fiel!!
.py scripts are running successfully, however the jupyter makes me crazy. The jupyter extension installed successfully, however   I got the error "Running cells with "python 3.9.6 64-bit' requires ipykernnel installed or requires an update".

So the problem is to install IPython Kernel for Jupyter. I have to install it offline. I went into https://pypi.org/project/ipykernel/
there is a download page, but I do not know how to install it offline.
Could you please let me know how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Could you have a look at this [page](https://lihaifeng.net/?p=375)?

Comment: Thanks Steven-MSFT, it was a clever solution, however the problem is I can not connect to the virtual machine via my personal laptop.